# Swiping multiple activities smootly

Tags: android

I have covered with Swiping problem. I have 3 activities and each activities is using downloading data from server. I want to make them smoothing horizontal scrolling as swiping.
i used to view pager and fragments but not got good solution.

please any one help

Answer (score 2):

Use view pager for three tab and download the data on MainActivity using AsyncTask. After each download finished, update fragment by callback interface. You can also store data in Application class to persist it through all the application.

Answer (score 1):

1. All the downloads should be performed at background
2. Use handler to update fragment UI
3. You could cache the root view of Fragment.onCreateView(), like the way you did in ListAdapter.getView()